# When I use the goto module,it works but I got an error: Exception TypeError

Tags: python, multithreading, goto

The goto module I install is form:[the module I installed](http://entrian.com/goto/download.html)

Here is the error:

> Exception TypeError: "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" in
>    ignored

Here is the code:

```
from goto import goto,label

for i in range(1,10) :
    print i
    if i == 9 :
        goto .say
    else:
        pass

label .say
print "find 9"
```

So Here is my code need to use goto:

```
#coding = utf-8

import requests
import threading
from goto import goto,label

nums = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
schars = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
chars = nums + schars

xml = ".xml"
root = "192.168.1.1:1900"
threads = 500
sem = threading.Semaphore(threads)

def get200(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code == 200 :
        print url

def match(filename,length) :
    if len(filename) <= (length +1):
        for char in chars :
            label.retry
            if sem.acquire :
                filename += char
                t = threading.Thread(target = get200,args = (root + filename + xml))
                t.start()
                sem.release()
                match(filename,length)
            else:
                goto.retry

    else :
        return

match('/',6)
```

Comment: That module was, as it clearly states in red text on that page, an April Fool's joke. It is well-known not to work properly.

Comment: But I really need to use goto in python,what should I do

Comment: "But I really need to use goto in python" _No you most certainly do not._

Comment: This code doesn't show you needing to use `goto` at all. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Someone else thinks they have source. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576944-the-goto-decorator/

Comment: this is a test,I need use goto in another code

Comment: No, you really don't.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Comment: @hellowanger Okay, now that you know Python doesn't have `goto` statement, think about how you can solve it without that

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question with the actual thing you need to do and we can help you do it without `goto`.

Comment: Hint: Python has functions, exceptions, the break and continue statements... in other words, flow control. You do not need goto.

Comment: Your example can easily be written to use `break` instead of goto. And I suspect that your real code can easily be written without goto, too.

Comment: "I need use goto in another code" No, you, do, not.

Comment: I 've add the code which really need goto,can somebody help me out?

Comment: @hellowanger and as everyone told you, your code **really doesn't** "need" a goto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need goto. Period. Just learn to use Python properly.

```
for i in range(1,10) :
    print i
    if i == 9 :
        print "find 9"
        break
```

Applied to your actual code, the solution is almost the same:

```
for char in chars :
    while True:
        if sem.acquire :
            filename += char
            t = threading.Thread(target=get200, args=(root + filename + xml))
            t.start()
            sem.release()
            match(filename,length)
            break
```

Which can be made even simpler:

```
for char in chars :
    while not sem.acquire:
        continue
    filename += char
    t = threading.Thread(target= get200, args=(root + filename + xml))
    t.start()
    sem.release()
    match(filename,length)
```

Comment: hello,I paste my code which really need to use goto.Can you help me out

Comment: @hellowanger cf my edited answer. All you need is a `while` loop and a `break`. You **DONT** need a goto. Period.

Comment: Tanks a lot .Using while and break really helped

Comment: @hellowanger you're welcome. FWIW you may want to check the alternate version using `continue`, which is even simpler. Seriously: you will **never** have a need for a goto statement (unless you're using a very low level or totally braindead language of course).

Answer (score 1):

The structured program theorem proved that the `goto` statement is not necessary to write programs.
Some combination of the three programming constructs of sequence, selection/choice, and repetition/iteration are sufficient for any computation that can be performed by a Turing machine, with the caveat that code duplication and additional variables may need to be introduced.

[Goto on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto)